# The one-way of speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time-dilation

My friend has a proposal to find the one-way speed of light.
Synchronize two local clocks 'A' and 'B' and then move B to one kilometre apart. But because of time dilation we know B would get dilated and asynchronized but we know by what amount it does. So manually can't we 'undo' the dilation effect (as we know by which amount time has been dilated). Hence, the two clocks will synchronized and we can measure one way speed of light? (within 1km of domain as per the experiment)

Comment: There is nothing that stops you from measuring one way speed of light in principle.

Comment: But i wanna know is this experimentally feasible?

Comment: Can you measure 3 nanoseconds?

Comment: How exactly did you derive the existence and extent of "time dilation" without assuming that light travels at the same speed in both directions?

Comment: There's an equation na which governs the time dilation if speed of light is not same in different directions.

Comment: @Ben51 can't we measure 3ns using atomic clock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do this experiment you will find that the one-way speed is $c$. The people who claim that it's impossible to measure the one-way speed of light will respond that you haven't really measured it because you made unwarranted assumptions about the effects of time dilation. If you use their time dilation formula instead of the standard one, you'll find that your clocks were desynchronized in just such a way that they showed a speed of $c$ even though the speed was really something else.

They've set it up so that you can't win: they redefine what the phrase "speed of light" means without changing any of the actual physical predictions of the theory, so nothing that you actually physically measure can falsify it.

It's just a word game, and it misses the point of what the constancy of the speed of light really means. See [this answer](//astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/39628) for more.

Comment: Your words are very crucial and in-fact deeper than I can think. So basically, what do you conclude? Is speed of light different in different directions or not? Because I myself don't convinced with the fact because it specifies absolutely no reason why light should behave like that!

Answer (score 1):

According to Hans Reichenbach in The Philosophy of Space and Time, from the perspective of special relativity, you cannot measure the speed of light.

> I briefly mention also Reichenbach’s view on the velocity of light. He
> asserts that there is no way of measuring the velocity of light and
> proving it is constant, because the measurement of the velocity of
> light requires the definition of simultaneity which depends on the
> speed of light. Einstein – Reichenbach says – does not prove the speed
> of light is constant, but the special theory of relativity assumes it
> is constant, i.e. it is constant by definition. https://iep.utm.edu/reichenb/

In your scenario you've assumed the Lorentz transformations. So, I believe you've already effectively assumed the speed of light is constant. (Because Einstein derived the Lorentz transformations from the assumption that the speed of light is constant.)

Einstein's simple popular derivation [*Relativity: The Special and General Theory*] begins by assuming

$x-ct=\lambda(x'-ct')$

And

$x+ct=\mu(x'+ct')$

Because $x'/t'=c$ if and only if $x/t=c$. The speed of light is c in both frames.

Comment: Einstein made that assumption but [it's actually not necessary](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.02423.pdf). "The structure of the Lorentz transformations follows purely from the absence of privileged inertial reference frames and the group structure... of the transformations—two assumptions that are simple and physically necessary." A finite speed limit (TBD experimentally) is then implied by the equations. So it comes out of them as a result; it doesn't go into them as a prerequisite.